# best way to place buttons on a png that will be a map

Tags: html, css

the title essentially explains all ,, 
I have a map img (png or jpg) and i want to place markers on the map that will scale if the resolution changes (media queries).  So points on a map that are buttons.. how do i do this ? Currently I have a container with a background image inside it that is the map...

```
#container-map{
    background-image: url(../img/map.png);
    z-index:9999;
    width:350px;
    height:900px;
    margin-left:150px;
    background-position: 0% 70%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

so how would i go about putting little markers on the image which is a map so i can then pull up info on the buttons that are selected ?

Comment: Nope, the title doesn't really explain it at all. In fact, I'm not sure at all what you're really asking even after reading the entire question.

Comment: using a background image that is a map ... how do i put markers on the map that are clickable and scale with the map , simple !

Comment: You're gonna have a really hard time mapping buttons to a background-image that can scale and change with the window size -- I'd recommend looking for a different approach.

Comment: thanks for the comment , what approach would you use ???

Comment: bare in mind I will be changing the height and width depending on media queries

Comment: One of the solutions is to use HTML Canvas element and draw markers with JS.

Comment: these guys have it locked down ! http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html

Comment: Another way is to use Google My Maps with custom markers.

Comment: @Dima we don't discuss way to do this with google maps, just an image. You idea with canvas pretty coll!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup to buttons `position: absolute` and make `z-index` of it more than on image.

Another way it setup a `background-image` of your block and then put markers on it.

Comment: @Dima why you need media queries here?

Comment: well yeah thats the issue perhaps i can overlay buttons/markers but i would have to change all markers relatively with the map img

Comment: @havingagoatit simply put div under another div, set margin's in % for markers

Comment: like it i have 30 markers so that is really helpful !

Comment: @havingagoatit nobody sad that will be easy:)

Comment: doesn't mean it is not worth doing though :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86625/discussion-between-aleshaoleg-and-havingagoatit).

Answer (score 0):

for more stability you can do this :

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/esctxsnm/5/)

use html `map` tag for points :

```
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126"  href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" id="venus" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
<label id="markup">!</label>
```

then using jQuery to get offset of each point and put your markup there:

```
var x = $("#venus").offset();
$("#markup").offset({top:x.top+58,left:x.left+124});
```

your css code :

```
#markup{
    display:block;
    width:6px;
    height:15px;
    background:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;
}
```